# Patching the kernel source through git

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, git, patch

I'm trying to understand how the patching of the kernel source works.
I found the patch that I would like to try an apply on the following [page](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/91626). I found no .patch files that I can use to apply the patch.

I would like to apply the patch on the kernel 3.10 source.

My current setup includes:

- 3.10 kernel source with a git repo inside
- remote pointing to https://github.com/hzpeterchen/linux-usb.git (this is the repo referenced in the patch mail)

Can someone please direct me to the next steps + the concepts behind the steps?

Comment: It seems the repository you've linked is a full git copy of Linux.

Comment: @enedil I saw that, yes. I thought that the patching through git would go through merging with that repository.
But the repository is kernel 3.13 so the idea doesn't seem sensible any more.